# Quiero generar un resultado con case cuando tengo una división entre cero

Tags: sql

Hola buenas tardes tengo este codigo de sql:

```
***SUM(CAST(pd.QTY AS NUMERIC)/p.PALLET) as Conversion***
```

Pero cuando p.PALLET vale cero me devuelve error por dividir entre '0'.
Quiero eliminar ese error colocando como resultado el número '0', y estoy haciendo e código
siguiente el cuál no me resulta. Me podrían ayudar por favor.

```
***SUM(CAST(pd.QTY AS NUMERIC)/(Case 
When p.PALLET = 0 then 0 
END)) as Pallets***
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! pero.. pero... When p.PALLET = 0 then 0  o sea.. cuando es 0 que ponga 0??? para mi, querias hacer otra cosa...

Comment: Algo así? `CASE WHEN p.PALLET = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(CAST(pd.QTY AS NUMERIC)/p.PALLET) END`

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 2):

El CASE tiene que rodear la operación completa.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN p.PALLET = 0 THEN 0 ELSE CAST(pd.QTY AS NUMERIC)/p.PALLET END) as Pallets
```